# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Cutoff at Low-resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added a carousel onto a church's website which is generated from a PHP script which can be configured within a remote backend.

This seems interesting as it only happens at low-resolutions.

Take a look here: http://cstone.jire.org/carousel.php

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width: 100%; height: 410px; position: fixed;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the `position: fixed` value you have set for the div `myCarousel`

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width: 100%; height: 410px; position: fixed;">
```

Remove `position: fixed`

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width: 100%; height: 410px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The image size is not large enough to stretch across the screen.  (1500px).

You can try add

width:100% to

```
.carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
display: block;
line-height: 1;
width: 100%;
```

}

But it might alter the height.

Comment: I added this and I don't think you know what I mean.

The image is cutoff on the right when you make the width of the page small.